# Absolute values with partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, partial-fractions

I've been evaluating the integral noted [here](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/int-0-1-x-4-x-2-5x-6-dx-evaluate-integral-481632), and I was wondering why the natural logs once you get to... $$[2ln(-1)-ln(-2)] - [2ln(-2)-ln(-3)]$$...aren't done with absolute values. Instead, why isn't this the answer? $$[2ln(1)-ln(2)] - [2ln(2)-ln(3)]$$

Thanks!

Comment: I think it might be a  mistake, but they arrive at the same answer. Note that for $z\in\Bbb R$ $|z^2|=z^2$.

Comment: Okay. But I'm not sure what you mean by that equation...

Comment: All its simply stating is that the absolute value of $z^2$ is equal to $z^2$ because $z$ is a real number. That is why $ln(|(-1)^{2}|)=ln(|1|)=0$.

Comment: Yeah, that appears to be a mistake. They just happen to get lucky and have the negatives cancel out later in the integral.